# Probability- Coin Flipping Game

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk, probability-limit-theorems

> If you play a game where you flip a coin if it lands heads you win £1 and tails you lose £1.If you start with $£K$ what is the probability that you are bankrupt after $n$ games?

**MY ATTEMPT**
I have just started learning about Short Random Walks, but I am not sure how to work this out while ruling out the possibility that the walk does not go below zero (play after bankruptcy) before the nth turn, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must of read about gambler ruin problem? You can use a variety of techniques to yield the result you desire. So look for gambler ruin on MSE. Also are you assuming the bank has unlimited funds as you will lose with probability 1 if you play indefinitely. Or is there a cap? But qualititively speaking you will have a higher probability of ruin if the bank has more capital (which it should have)

Comment: 1. Does bankrupt mean having no money left, or having no money left and still owing the bank a pound? 2. If you get bankrupt before $n$ games, are you considered out of the game, or do you continue playing with no money at hand? (The method of solving would be almost the same, though.)

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code No I mean having no more money and being out of the game

Comment: @Chinny84 Yes the bank has infinite money, the follow on question is to show that you will lose with probability 1 if you play indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we keep on playing even if we go bankrupt (possibly ending in negative numbers as if ending with debt), the money you have after $n$ coin-flips would be distributed like $X = K-n + 2 Bin(0.5,n)$ where $Bin(p,n)$ denotes a binomial distribution.

An important observation is that the probability of reaching $0$ pounds somewhere during gambling and ending with $k$ pounds is the same as the probability of ending with $-k$ pounds. You can see this by flipping the last part of the random walk after reaching zero. Therefore, the probabilty of going bankrupt is $2P\{X<0\} + P\{X=0\}$.

This is $2P\{Bin(0.5,n)<\frac{n-k}{2}\} + P\{Bin(0.5,n)=\frac{n-k}{2}\}$ which you can calculate exactly or you can approximate this using the central limit theorem.

Comment: Notice that as $n$ gets larger the probability of a bankruptcy approaches 1.

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain how you got the formulation for X in the third line? and when saying $Bin(0.5,n)$ do you mean a random variable with that distribution?

Comment: Is this the probability that he is bankrupt after exactly n games i.e $S_i \neq 0 \forall i=1,...,n-1$ and $S_n=0$??

Comment: Sorry i should have used ~ in stead of = but I didn't know how to write that

Comment: No, this is the probability that he went bankrupt somewhere before or exacly after the $n$-th game.

Comment: How do we compute the probability he becomes bankrupt at the $n^{th}$ game?

Comment: Chance that he is bankrupt before or on $n$-th game minus chance of bankruptcy before or on the $(n-1)$-th game

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, last question, for the formulation of $X$ money after n games, I know $K$ is initial wealth, why the minus $n$? And the 2Bin(0.5,n), why two of these? Again apologies if these questions are stupid.

Comment: Say $Y$ is the number of coinflips you win. This means $Y$ is distributed like $Bin(0.5,n)$. The number af coin flips you lose is then $n-Y$. You win one pound for each game you win and you lose one pound for each game you lose, so the change in money is $Y - (n-Y) = 2Y-n$